# Hashing Data greater than or equal to 56 bytes

Tags: c++, sha1

I'm trying to understand the internal mechanism used in the SHA-1 hash function. I'm also referring to the FIPS-180 standard.

Managed to write an implementation is able to return accurate results hashing a string "abc". However I'm still blunt how to interpret strings >= 56 bytes. The FIPS-180 standard specifies to use 1024bit for a string size of 56 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sha1 operates on messages with block size of 512bits (64 bytes).

What happens if you have a message of length 104 bytes? First you need to pad the message in order to be able to operate on blocks of size 512bits.

You take the incomplete last block of 104 - 64 = 40 bytes, and go through the message padding phase that is described in fips-180 in order to get a block size of 512bits (64bytes), and perform the message digest calculation.

The padding phase (taken from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1)) is:

```
Pre-processing:
append the bit '1' to the message
append 0 ≤ k < 512 bits '0', so that the resulting message length (in bits) is congruent to 448 ≡ −64 (mod 512)
append length of message (before pre-processing), in bits, as 64-bit big-endian integer
```

Comment: Your solution covers scenarios where values are greater than 56 bytes (448 bits), another scenario which is mentioned in the FIPS-180 standard. Where are a string equals 56 bytes it uses two 512 bits, so does it mean if I can't append 0x80 in the byte following the message. Would I have to redo the operation all over again in another message schedule?

Comment: If the message is 56bytes, after the pre-processing phase you will have 2 blocks of 512bits since the first step adds bit '1' to the message block and the 7bits that are left are not enough to hold the 8bit length that one must add on the last block. So yes in this example you need to do the pre-processing step before you go further with message digest calculations. Once pre-processing is done, you will have two 512bits blocks that are used by the digest calculation function.

Answer (score 1):

In case you care to look through it, here's some code I wrote as kind of a "reference implementation" a few years ago -- it's intended more to map reasonably closely to the standards, than to be fast, efficient, etc.

sha1.h:

```
#ifndef SHA_1_H_INCLUDED_
#define SHA_1_H_INCLUDED_

// This is a relatively straightforward implementation of SHA-1. It makes no particular
// attempt at optimization, instead aiming toward easy verification against the standard.
// To that end, many of the variable names are identical to those used in FIPS 180-2 and
// FIPS 180-3. 
//
// The code should be fairly portable, within a few limitations:
// 1. It requires that 'char' have 8 bits. In theory this is avoidable, but I don't think
// it's worth the bother.
// 2. It only deals with inputs in (8-bit) bytes. In theory, SHA-1 can deal with a number of 
// bits that's not a multiple of 8, but I've never needed it. Since the padding always results
// in a byte-sized stream, the only parts that would need changing would be reading and padding
// the input. The main hashing portion would be unaffected.
//
// Compiles cleanly with:
//    MS VC++ 9.0SP1 (x86 or x64): -W4 -Za
//    gc++ 3.4: -ansi -pedantic -Wall
//    comeau 4.3.3: --vc71 
// Appears to work corectly in all cases. 
// You can't use maximum warnings with Comeau though -- this code itself doesn't give problems
// (that I know of) but Microsoft's headers give it *major* heartburn.
// 
//
// Written by Jerry Coffin, February 2008
// 
// You can use this software any way you want to, with following limitations
// (shamelessly stolen from the Boost software license):
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, TITLE AND NON-INFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT
// SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS OR ANYONE DISTRIBUTING THE SOFTWARE BE LIABLE
// FOR ANY DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE,
// ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
// DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
// 
// If you put this to real use, I'd be happy to hear about it. If you find a bug, 
// I'd be interested in hearing about that too. There's even a pretty good chance 
// that I'll try to fix it, though I certainly can't guarantee that.
// 
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

#if defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER < 1600
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
typedef unsigned __int64 uint64_t;
#else
#include <stdint.h>
#endif

namespace crypto { 
namespace {
    struct ternary_operator { 
        virtual uint32_t operator()(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z) = 0;
    };
}

class sha1 { 
    static const size_t hash_size = 5;
    static const size_t min_pad = 64;
    static const size_t block_bits = 512;
    static const size_t block_bytes = block_bits / 8;
    static const size_t block_words = block_bytes / 4;

    std::vector<uint32_t> K;
    std::vector<uint32_t> H;
    std::vector<uint32_t> W;
    std::vector<ternary_operator *> fs;
    uint32_t a, b, c, d, e, T;
    static const size_t block_size = 16;
    static const size_t bytes_per_word = 4;
    size_t total_size;

    // hash a 512-bit block of input.
    //
    void hash_block(std::vector<uint32_t> const &block);

    // Pad the input to a multiple of 512 bits, and add the length
    // in binary to the end.
    static std::string pad(std::string const &input, size_t size);

    // Turn 64 bytes into a block of 16 uint32_t's.
    std::vector<uint32_t> make_block(std::string const &in);

public:

    // Construct a SHA-1 object. More expensive that typical 
    // ctor, but not expected to be copied a lot or anything
    // like that, so it should be fairly harmless.
    sha1();

    // The two ways to provide input for hashing: as a stream or a string.
    // Either way, you get the result as a vector<uint32_t>. It's a fairly
    // small vector, so even if your compiler doesn't do return-value 
    // optimization, the time it takes isn't like to be significant.
    // 
    std::vector<uint32_t> operator()(std::istream &in);
    std::vector<uint32_t> operator()(std::string const &input);

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, sha1 const &s);
};
}

#endif
```

And the implementation:

```
// Sha1.cpp:
#include "sha.h"
// Please see comments in sha.h for licensing information, etc.
//

// Many people don't like the names I usually use for namespaces, so I've kept this one
// short and simple.
//
namespace crypto {
namespace {
//    void show(char const *caption, sha1 const &s, std::ostream &os) {
//        os << caption << s;
//    }

uint32_t ROTL(uint32_t const &value, unsigned bits) { 
    uint32_t mask = (1 << bits) - 1;
    return value << bits | (value >> (32-bits))&mask;
}

struct f1 : ternary_operator {
    uint32_t operator()(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z) { 
        return (x & y) ^ (~x&z);
    }
};

struct f2 : ternary_operator {
    uint32_t operator()(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z) {
        return x ^ y ^ z;
    }
};

struct f3 : ternary_operator {
    uint32_t operator()(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z) {
        return (x&y) ^ (x&z) ^ (y&z);
    }
};

uint32_t word(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    a &= 0xff;
    b &= 0xff;
    c &= 0xff;
    d &= 0xff;
    int val =  a << 24 | b << 16 | c << 8 | d;
    return val;
}
}

// hash a 512-bit block of input.
//
void sha1::hash_block(std::vector<uint32_t> const &block) {
    assert(block.size() == block_words);

    int t;
    std::copy(block.begin(), block.end(), W.begin());
    for (t=16; t<80; t++) {
        W[t] = ROTL(W[t-3] ^ W[t-8] ^ W[t-14] ^ W[t-16], 1);
    }

    a = H[0]; b = H[1]; c = H[2]; d = H[3]; e = H[4];

    for (t=0; t<80; t++) {
        T = ROTL(a, 5) + (*fs[t])(b, c, d) + e + K[t] + W[t];
        e = d;
        d = c;
        c = ROTL(b, 30);
        b = a;
        a = T;
    }
    H[0] += a; H[1] += b; H[2] += c; H[3] += d; H[4] += e;
}

// Pad the input to a multiple of 512 bits, and add the length
// in binary to the end.
std::string sha1::pad(std::string const &input, size_t size) {
    size_t length = size * 8 + 1;
    size_t remainder = length % block_bits;
    size_t pad_len = block_bits-remainder;

    if (pad_len < min_pad)
        pad_len += block_bits;
    ++pad_len;

    pad_len &= ~7;
    std::string padding(pad_len/8, '\0');

    for (size_t i=0; i<sizeof(padding.size()); i++)
        padding[padding.size()-i-1] = (length-1) >> (i*8) & 0xff;
    padding[0] |= (unsigned char)0x80;

    std::string ret(input+padding);
    return ret;
}

// Turn 64 bytes into a block of 16 uint32_t's.
std::vector<uint32_t> sha1::make_block(std::string const &in) { 
    assert(in.size() >= block_bytes);

    std::vector<uint32_t> ret(block_words);

    for (size_t i=0; i<block_words; i++) {
        size_t s = i*4;
        ret[i] = word(in[s], in[s+1], in[s+2], in[s+3]);
    }
    return ret;
}


// Construct a SHA-1 object. More expensive that typical 
// ctor, but not expected to be copied a lot or anything
// like that, so it should be fairly harmless.
sha1::sha1() : K(80), H(5), W(80), fs(80), total_size(0) {
    static const uint32_t H0[] = { 
        0x67452301, 0xefcdab89, 0x98badcfe, 0x10325476, 0xc3d2e1f0
    };
    static const uint32_t Ks[] = {
        0x5a827999, 0x6ed9eba1, 0x8f1bbcdc, 0xca62c1d6
    };

    std::copy(H0, H0+hash_size, H.begin());

    std::fill_n(K.begin()+00, 20, Ks[0]);
    std::fill_n(K.begin()+20, 20, Ks[1]);
    std::fill_n(K.begin()+40, 20, Ks[2]);
    std::fill_n(K.begin()+60, 20, Ks[3]);

    static f1 sf1;
    static f2 sf2;
    static f3 sf3;

    std::fill_n(fs.begin()+00, 20, &sf1);
    std::fill_n(fs.begin()+20, 20, &sf2);
    std::fill_n(fs.begin()+40, 20, &sf3);
    std::fill_n(fs.begin()+60, 20, &sf2);
}

// The two ways to provide input for hashing: as a stream or a string.
// Either way, you get the result as a vector<uint32_t>. It's a fairly
// small vector, so even if your compiler doesn't do return-value 
// optimization, the time it takes isn't likely to be significant.
// 
std::vector<uint32_t> sha1::operator()(std::string const &input) { 
    std::string temp(pad(input, total_size + input.size()));
    std::vector<uint32_t> block(block_size);

    size_t num = temp.size()/block_bytes;

    for (unsigned block_num=0; block_num<num; block_num++) {
        size_t s;
        for (size_t i=0; i<block_size; i++) {
            s = block_num*block_bytes+i*4;
            block[i] = word(temp[s], temp[s+1], temp[s+2], temp[s+3]);
        }
        hash_block(block);  
    }
    return H;
}

std::vector<uint32_t> sha1::operator()(std::istream &in) { 
    char raw_block[65];

    while (in.read(raw_block, block_bytes)) {
        total_size += block_bytes;
        std::string b(raw_block, in.gcount());
        hash_block(make_block(b));
    }
    std::string x(raw_block, in.gcount());
    return operator()(x);
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, sha1 const &s) { 
    // Display a SHA-1 result in hex.
    for (size_t i=0; i<(s.H).size(); i++)
        os << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8) << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << (s.H)[i] << " ";
    return os << std::dec << std::setfill(' ') << "\n";
}

}

#ifdef TEST
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

// A minimal test harness to check that it's working correctly. Strictly black-box
// testing, with no attempt at things like coverage analysis. Nonetheless, I believe
// it should cover most of the code -- the core hashing code all gets used for every
// possible value. The padding code should be tested fairly thoroughly as well -- the
// first test is a fairly simple case, and the second the more complex one (where the 
// padding requires adding another block).
class tester {
    bool verify(uint32_t *test_val, std::vector<uint32_t> const &hash, std::ostream &os) {
        // Verify that a result matches a test value and report result.
        for (size_t i=0; i<hash.size(); i++)
            if (hash[i] != test_val[i]) {
                os << "Mismatch. Expected: " << test_val[i] << ", but found: " << hash[i] << "\n";
                return false;
            }
            os << "Message digest Verified.\n\n";
            return true;
    }

public:

    bool operator()(uint32_t *test_val, std::string const &input) {
        std::cout << "Testing hashing from string:\n\"" << input << "\"\n";
        crypto::sha1 hasher1;
        std::vector<uint32_t> hash = hasher1(input);
        std::cout << "Message digest is:\n\t" << hasher1;
        bool verified = verify(test_val, hash, std::cerr);

        crypto::sha1 hasher2;
        std::cout << "Testing hashing from Stream:\n";
        std::istringstream buf(input);
        hash = hasher2(buf);
        std::cout << "Message digest is:\n\t" << hasher2;

        return verified & verify(test_val, hash, std::cerr);
    }
};

int main() {
    // These test values and results come directly from the SHA-1 FIPS pub.
    //
    char const *input1 = "abc";
    char const *input2 = "abcdbcdecdefdefgefghfghighijhijkijkljklmklmnlmnomnopnopq";
    uint32_t result1[] = {0xA9993E36, 0x4706816A, 0xBA3E2571, 0x7850C26C, 0x9CD0D89D};
    uint32_t result2[] = {0x84983E44, 0x1C3BD26E, 0xBAAE4AA1, 0xF95129E5, 0xE54670F1};
    bool correct = tester()(result1, input1);
    correct &= tester()(result2, input2);
    if (correct)
        std::cerr << "All Tests passed!\n";
    else
        std::cerr << "Test Failed!\n";
}
#elif defined(MAIN) 

#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: sha1 [filename]\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    for (int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        crypto::sha1 hash;
        std::ifstream in(argv[i], std::ios_base::binary);
        if (in.good()) {
            hash(in);
            std::cout << "SHA-1(" << argv[i] << ") = " << hash << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
#endif
```